# NAudio.Midi Delay with MidiIn

Tags: midi, naudio

In my MIDI-Application I use NAudio. (Great!) But if I play on my midi-keyboard, there is always a delay. Here is my code:

```
private MidiOut @out = new MidiOut(0);
private void InitMidiOut()
{
    MidiIn midiIn = new MidiIn(0);
    midiIn.MessageReceived += midiIn_MessageReceived;
   midiIn.Start();
}

private void midiIn_MessageReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MidiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOn) {
        @out.Send(e.RawMessage);
    }
}
```

I understand that there is a delay with WaveOut, but why with MidiOut?
Is there a way to minimize the delay?

Comment: What component (software or hardware) are you using to convert MIDI to actual sounds?

Comment: At the moment Windows 7 builtin quartz.dll.

Comment: That DLL does not contain a MIDI synthesizer. What output device are you using?

Comment: Software is the builtin “Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth”. The Output Device is Creative Xmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NAudio.

Microsoft's built-in software synthesizer was originally written for playback of MIDI files, where real-time responses are not needed, so it uses high latency to decrease the risk of dropouts.

You have to replace it with some other synthesizer that allows operation with lower latency (for example, [VirtualMIDISynth](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed VirtualMIDISynth and some nice Soundfonts. Now the sound is much better. But the delay is the same.

Comment: What latency did you configure?

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't notice, that I can configure the latency in VirtulaMIDISynth. I set it to 0 and now there is no latency any more.

Answer (score 0):

latency can be introduced at several stages. But NAudio is a fairly thin wrapper onto the `midi...` Windows APIs and so I'd expect the receive and send to happen quite quickly. What are you using to actually produce the sounds?

Comment: At the moment it's the builtin builtin “Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Look at my comments to CL. I use a app for music notation ("capella") and there is no latency, whether I use “Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth” or VirtualMIDISynth as CL recommended.